# Gradle not working in android studio [flutter]

Tags: android-studio, flutter, gradle, dart, compiler-errors

When I executed my code for the first time on the android studio ( flutter - dart project ) I got the below error

[image: Error message]

I tried deleting it from  `%HOME%.gradle`

I even tried deleting and re-installing `JDK` but I'm still facing the same problem.

and here is a picture of my environment variables and path if it may help

[image: Environment variables]

Comment: What does your flutter doctor say? `flutter doctor -v`

Comment: first, check your internet connection use VPN if you in a restricted country don't forget to check auto-detect proxy if you using android studio settings .run flutter doctor for more information

Comment: for flutter doctor , only the android toolchain isn't checked , even tho it was checked a while ago

Comment: From inside your android dir, try and run `gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace` to check what causes the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what worked for me : 
i changed my user name ( as you can see it was MystoGan! 
)  ,  it had an ' ! ' on it so i figured it might be the problem,  so after changing it and completely deleting android studio,  i installed it again and it worked